# "SIGSEGV ON THREAD", alguém me ajuda a resolver, e também se possível, a completar o programa?

Tags: c, if, for, while, int

É o seguinte, faço um técnico de info, e estou aprendendo C a apenas dois bimestres, e sei pouco ainda. Recentemente o meu professor pediu para fazer um programa em que usuário entrasse com dois número num, e que cada posição de dois vetores n, fossem preenchidas de forma decrescente com cada digito desse número.
Ex: O usuário digitou 284, o vetor (de 100 posições) vai ter a pos 100 = 0, a 99 = 0, (...) a 3 = 2, a 2 = 8 e a 1 = 4.
E a partir daí, precisamos simular uma adição, uma subtração uma divisão e uma multiplicação, trabalhando apenas com essas casas dos vetores.

A saída da parte da adição seria mais ou menos assim:

```
       1
[0][0][2][5][4]
+
[0][0][1][9][4]
=
[0][0][4][4][8]
```

Bem complicado sabendo que só se pode trabalhar com as casas do vetor né?!

Esse é o problema, daqui eu n estou conseguindo prosseguir por causa do erro do título, veja meu código:

```
    #include <stdio.h> 
int n[10], n2[10], num, nun, i=9, j=9, sv=0, on, res[4][20], opc[4][20];
main(){
        printf("Insert the 1st number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        sv = num;
        while (num != 0)
    {
            n[i] = num%10;
            num = num/10; 
            i--;
    }
        num = sv;
        printf("Insert the 2nd number: ");
        scanf("%d", &nun);
        sv = nun;
        while (nun != 0)
        {
            n2[j] = nun%10;
            nun = nun/10; 
            j--;
        }
        nun = sv;
        printf("Select an operation (1=addition; 2=subtraction; 3=multiplication; 4=division): ");
        scanf("%d", &on);
        while((on>4)||(on<0)){
            printf("Try again: ");
            scanf("%d", &on);
        }
        for (j=0; j<4; j++){
            for (i=19; i>=0; i--){
                opc[j][i]=0;
            }
        }
        if (on==1)
        {
        for (i=10; i>=1; i++){
            if ((n[i] + n2[i] + opc[1][10+i]) <= 9)
            {
                opc[1][10+i] += (n[i] + n2[i]);
            }
            if ((n[i] + n2[i] + opc[1][10+i]) > 9)
            {
                opc[1][10+i] += (n[i] + n2[i])%10;
                opc[1][9+i] += (n[i] + n2[i])/10;
            }
        }
        for (i=0; i<=9; i++){
            printf("|%d|", n[i]);
        }
        printf("\n+\n");
        for (i=0; i<=9; i++){
            printf("|%d|", n2[i]);
        }
        printf("\n=\n");
            for (i=19; i>=0; i--){
        printf("|%d|", opc[1][i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Coming soon :)");
    }   
}
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar a resolver esse erro, ou até sugerir como eu posso fazer o resto do programa, eu seria muito grato, já estou a uma semana trabalhando nisso, fazendo os outros exercícios, mas esse está extremamente difícil.

Comment: Um vector de `100` elementos não tem posição `100`, pois vai de `0` a `99`. O numero seria guardado da casa `0` para a frente ?

Comment: No caso é decrescente msm